# SVN::Client - how can I get the latest revision number of a file?

Tags: perl, svn

I'm using [SVN::Client](http://search.cpan.org/%7Emschwern/Alien-SVN-v1.8.11.0/src/subversion/subversion/bindings/swig/perl/native/Client.pm) in a Perl script. The documentation demonstrates how to get info about a file stored in SVN:

> `$client->info($path_or_url, $peg_revision, $revision, \&receiver, $recurse)`;
>
> Invokes `\&receiver` passing it information about `$path_or_url` for `$revision`. **The information returned is system-generated metadata, not the sort of "property" metadata created by users.** For methods available on the object passed to `\&receiver`, see `svn_info_t`.

```
 my $receiver = sub {
     my( $path, $info, $pool ) = @_;
     print "Current revision of $path is ", $info->rev, "\n";
 };
 $client->info( 'foo/bar.c', undef, 'WORKING', $receiver, 0 );
```

I want to return `$info->rev`, but trying something like

```
my $rev_num = $client->info('foo/bar.c', undef, 'WORKING', $receiver, 0);
```

returns `undef`. (obviously, modify the above code snippet to `return $info->rev`)

Is there any way I can retrieve this information (or otherwise extract `$info` from this method)?